# not able to send request to express server using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I am building a chat application like whatsapp, & implementing the feature - when user clicks on any person's name, his chats appears, but can't able to send request to server when user clicks

[Source code](https://github.com/bhupesh8222/ChatApplication)

There is div, when user will click on it, it will fetch data from server (onclick event handler) in [Sidebar.js file -](https://github.com/bhupesh8222/ChatApplication/blob/master/client/src/Sidebar.js)

```
{friends.map((e) => (
                    <div
                        onClick={getChatDetails}
                        key={e.friendName}
                        className='sidebar_chat_info'>
                        <Avatar />
                        <div>
                            <h2>{e.friendName}</h2>
                            <p>{getLastMessage()}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
```

this is getChatDetails function in sidebar.js file

```
const getChatDetails = (e) => {
    //console.log(e.target.textContent);
    const Myfriend = e.target.textContent;
    axios
        .post('http://localhost:2000/message/get', { friend: Myfriend })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
};
```

At the server side , this is route in [index.js file](https://github.com/bhupesh8222/ChatApplication/blob/master/server/index.js)

Server is running on port 2000

```
app.post('/message/get', isloggedIn, async (req, res) => {
console.log('REQUESTED!');

try {
    const conversation = await req.user.MyConversation.find(
        (element) => element.friendName == req.body.friend
    );
    const messages = await conversationModel.findById(conversation.chats);
    res.send(messages);
    //await MessageModel.remove({})
} catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
}
});
```

[This is error on browser console , when I am clicking on div](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aFx_RVqqHALB6APpFfyH-zr7_z5-0Or7/view?usp=sharing)

[But when I am sending request through postman, I am getting response](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IAqnuPJfI8c6pMFyJAU2C4tJd2eUvhuE/view?usp=sharing)

When I am sending request in other files (login.js), it's working there, don't know why it is not working only Sidebar.js file

Comment: You should console.log the error in your catch clause. Something must go wrong in the try/catch

Comment: What does MyFriend return in the console when you log it? Also, that should be myFriend btw. In JS, variables with two words should be camelCase. As Postman gives you a valid response, I'm going to say that it is an issue with your getChatDetails method.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you're having is that e in getChatDetails is undefined. The reason for this is is onclick does not pass an event object. In order to pass an event object to your sidebar function, you need to attach an event listener to it, which is a bit better than using onclick in most cases anyways (imo). Something like this:

```
const sidebar = document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar_chat_info')

for (let i = 0; i < sidebar.length; i++) {
  sidebar[i].addEventListener('click', handleClick = e => {
    //console.log(e.target.textContent);
    const Myfriend = e.target.textContent;
    axios
        .post('http://localhost:2000/message/get', { friend: Myfriend })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

The middleware "isLoggedIn" causing issue. The problem was in my authentication part, when the user has been logged in then only he will see home page

[index.js file at line 113](https://github.com/bhupesh8222/ChatApplication/blob/master/server/index.js)

I added console.log and found that "NOT LOGGED IN " is displayed

```
function isloggedIn(req, res, next) {
if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
} else {
    console.log('NOT LOGGED IN !');
    res.status(500).send('DENIED PERMISSION!');
}
}
```

I think it is happening because after logging in , I am redirecting to home page from
[Login.js](https://github.com/bhupesh8222/ChatApplication/blob/master/client/src/Login.js)   at line 59

**history.push('/', { user: response.data });**

```
const submitForm = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
        .post('http://localhost:2000/login', {
            username: username,
            password: password,
        })
        .then((response) => {
            history.push('/', { user: response.data });
        })
        .catch((error) => setIsError(true));

    //console.log(user.data); //user.data contains the details
    //CALLING THE HOME PAGE AFTER SIGNUP & SENDING DETAILS OF CURRENT USER THERE !
    //history.push('/', { user: user.data });
};
```

Maybe the request will be authenticated only from Login.js file, but I can't make other request from this file like getting chats details, sending message etc. I will have to go to home page . That's why I am redirecting to home page after logging in
On home page my request is not authenticated.

In postman all routes are working as I am not switching pages.

Login and logout routes are working as they are not taking in account "isLoggedIn"

Please suggest how to work with routes that needs authentication, like send message, gettingchats details?

PS - My request is even not authenticated from Login.js. After logging in, this time I didn't redirect to home page. I made request to route that needs authentication after logging in , it's still showing "NOT LOGGED IN" on server